# Link to tab in other page using link_to in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, ruby-on-rails-4

How do you **link to a different page and activating a tab using link_to** from the scaffold generated code.

```
<%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                root_path, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
```

i tried this but it didn't work either:

```
<%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                root_path('#panel_projects'), :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
```

Where as #panel_projects is the tab link which i want the users to get to after getting redirected.

Does anybody know how to accomplish this? **Preferably without Javascript.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `anchor` (find it in the [examples](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)) parameter:

```
<%= link_to(
      t('.cancel', :default => t('helpers.links.cancel')),
      root_path(anchor: 'panel_projects'), 
      :class => 'btn btn-default') %>
```

Comment: This does bring me to the link localhost:3000/panel_projects but it doesn't activate that tab, it just shows the first tab.

Comment: How did you implement which tab is active (by using a css class, the target selector, javascript)?

Comment: With a css class 'tab-pane fade in active' but the tab which is activated has been commented out by me. So now there is no active tab, it just goes to the first tab automatically.

Comment: That means you implemented something that uses javascript, but want a solution without javascript? That is not possible. You must implement the tabs as a non javascript (for example target selector based) version first.